# Android UDP glitches cause VOIP stutters

Tags: android, networking, udp, webrtc, jitter

I am debugging a RTC video stutters issues on Android and I tried serval different devices. To simplify the question, I just keep sending udp packets with an interval about 10ms from a MAC and  receiving them on Android with a good wifi. I can see big jitters (bigger than 200ms) almost every minute, can be bigger than 600ms sometimes. Especially when I open and close a task manager. Not duplicated with localhost testing. Can this be fixed?

```
while(1) {
    int s = recvfrom(socket_fd, buffer,  sizeof(buffer), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&recv_addr, (socklen_t *)&addr_len);
    if (s > 0) {
        struct timeval tv_ioctl;
        tv_ioctl.tv_sec = 0;
        tv_ioctl.tv_usec = 0;
        int error = ioctl(socket_fd, SIOCGSTAMP, &tv_ioctl);
        if (error == 0) {
            int64_t ms = tv_ioctl.tv_sec * 1000LL + tv_ioctl.tv_usec/1000;
            if (pre_rev_ms == 0) {
                pre_rev_ms = ms;
            }
            if (ms - pre_rev_ms > 200) {
                LOGV("Udp glitches\n");
            }
            pre_rev_ms = ms;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Jitter is caused by congestion on the network. You need to fix the network.

Comment: Most of the jitters are from network congestions, they can be reduced by congestion control. What  I am talking about here is a unique  issue only for Android. As I tested the same way with MAC and iOS devices. I know  we can not avoid all the network jitters, but for Android, it looks like we are suffering much more extra glitches. As we are developing a really low-latency(End to end 200ms) RTC product,  a big jitterbuffer is not acceptable. So we need to finger out all the jitters which are not really caused by network congestion or weak signals.